# Is it better to nest multiple navigators in a stack or switch navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have both a Material Top Tab Navigator and a Drawer Navigator and both successfully display when either are nested inside a Stack/Switch Navigator. However I can't tell the difference. Is there any difference to using either one and if so which is better or is it down to preference.

The following is what I'm using at the moment with a Switch Navigator:

```js
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        Calculator: {
            screen: CalculatorScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({}) => (
                    <Icon name='ios-calculator' size={28} color='#FFF'/>
                )
            }
        },
        Camera: {
            screen: CameraScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({}) => (
                    <Icon name='ios-camera' size={28} color='#FFF'/>
                )
            }
        },
        Solution: {
            screen: SolutionScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({}) => (
                    <Icon name='ios-paper' size={28} color='#FFF'/>
                )
            }
        }
    },
    {
        animationEnabled: false,
        initialRouteName: 'Camera',
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBarOptions: {
            showIcon: true,
            showLabel: false,
            indicatorStyle: {
                opacity: 0
            },
            style: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                right: 0
            }
        }
    }
)

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Contact: {
            screen: TabNavigator
        }
    },
    {
        drawerBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.9)',
        contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#fff',
            activeBackgroundColor: '#6b52ae',
        },
    }
);

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Drawer: {
            screen: DrawerNavigator
        },
        Screen: {
            screen: TabNavigator
        }
    }
)

export default AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator)
```

In this either case I get desirable results that are almost identical. So my only questions are which is better and what are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a `switchnavigator` and a `stacknavigator` is whether you stack the stack or not. `StackNavigator` builds up the stack by default each time you move the screen. This means that you'll see the screen on top of the screen You can therefore execute the 'goBack()' button. However, the `switchnavigator` does not stack. The `switchnavigator` **resets** the path as it moves the screen.

> **SwitchNavigator**: The purpose of `SwitchNavigator` is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions
>   and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away
>
> **StackNavigator**: Provides a way for your app to transition between screens where each new screen is placed on top of a stack.

Comment: Thanks, I assume this means for nesting other navigators that don't interact with each other a switch navigator is better.